# How to disable Cow/Sheep/Horse/Elephant tile sounds?

Tags: civilization-5

I am hearing Cow/Sheep/Horse sounds coming from the tiles. This is despite having ambience audio volume set to zero. I only have Sound Effect volume above zero.

I find those noises should be ambience, much like when you zoom in on a city, you hear car honk sounds. They are not event sounds or interface interaction sounds. They just randomly go `baa` while sitting on the map.

How can I silence the lambs?

I tried searching for the MP3 file without luck.

Out of all the animals. I think the sheep noises are the worst of all. I rather not play the game with no sounds.

Comment: I think the title of this question should be just "How can I silence the lambs?"

Comment: Are you looking for a way to silence the lambs without turning off sound effects

Comment: You'll need to create a small mod to change the animal sounds from effects to ambient sounds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a solution. I figured it out by searching all files that contained the word "Sheep". I discarded scenario and civlopedia files and found this file.
`Audio3DScripts.xml`

I found that file in (could be different for yours)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common
    \sid meier's civilization v\assets\Sounds\XML
```

There are two ways, either changing the min and max volume or changing the category of the sound.

Changing the max an min volume being the second preferred option by changing both to zero.

**The recommended option** is to change the `<SoundType>` from `GAME_SFX` to `GAME_AMBIENCE`

A typical sound entry looks like this. (Since I played an map that showed an elephant, i used that as my test)

```
<Script3DSound>
  <ScriptID>AS3D_RESOURCE_ELEPHANT_ELEPHANT_FOOT</ScriptID>
  <SoundID>SND_UNIT_ELEPHANT_FOOT</SoundID>
  <SoundType>GAME_SFX</SoundType>
  <iMaxVolume>65</iMaxVolume>
  <iMinVolume>50</iMinVolume>
  <iPitchChangeDown>-3</iPitchChangeDown>
  <iPitchChangeUp>1</iPitchChangeUp>
  <fMinDistance>0.35</fMinDistance>
</Script3DSound>
<Script3DSound>
  <ScriptID>AS3D_RESOURCE_ELEPHANT_VOX</ScriptID>
  <SoundID>SND_UNIT_ELEPHANT_VOX</SoundID>
  <SoundType>GAME_SFX</SoundType>
  <iMaxVolume>30</iMaxVolume>
  <iMinVolume>15</iMinVolume>
  <fMinDistance>0.25</fMinDistance>
</Script3DSound>
```

All i did was change the `min` and `max` volume to 0 **or** change the `soundtype`.

Both worked in my tests; no more elephant sounds. You will see there were two entries for the elephant, one for a foot shuffle and one for an elephant call. A few of the animals (or other things) have more than one sound. So just change the type or turn the volume down on the ones "annoying" you.

The file is not long and includes sounds for the following animals.

```
Whale (blow / splash / song / tail slap)
Sea Gulls
Fish (although i dont recall the sound of fish in the game)
Horse (blow / paw ground / snort)
Chew grass (could be cow)
Cow (moo)
Elephant (foot shuffle/ voice)
Sheep (Baa)
```

Ha, I silenced the lambs!
*It puts the lotion on its skin or else it gets the hose again.*

Special mention:

```
Volcanoes
Gyser
Ocean waves splashing on the shore (a number of different ones)
Mermaids (Siren)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sheep/Cows/Horses are not ambient sounds. They're effects. Turn off the effects sound option. This will silence those cursed lambs.

Comment: Why is this down-voted? It's correct.

Comment: It may be correct, but I think Valamas might be looking for a more targeted assassination of the livestock noises, rather than leaving himself without any effect noises (or any sound at all if he only has the effects volume above zero). While I'm not sure if your answer deserves to be as heavily downvoted as it is, I can certainly see how it might attract a few downvotes.

Comment: Plus he already explained that cars honks are treated as ambient noises, not effects, so it makes no sense that animal noises would be different.

Comment: I haven't played Civ 5. But are the animals part of a resource or is their presence purely aesthetic. Car honks sound aesthetic while sounds a resource tile might make may be more significant therefore not fall under ambience.

Comment: The fact that the Civ 5 designers put animal sounds under the wrong category isn't the answerer's fault.

Comment: Wow, I wake up to a lot of activity. My response is this answer does not answer my question. Reality or philosophy as to whether the sounds are in or not or should be or not, in ambience; does not answer how to silence the lambs.

Comment: @Lawton however, the fact that the question itself already alluded to the information contained in this answer makes the answer unhelpful, which is what downvotes are for.

Comment: Upvoted, This seems like a decent alternative to people not wanting to mess with the files.